# USB Keyboard stuck in repeat on first key hit after waking from sleep fixed by reconnecting

Tags: usb, keyboard, kubuntu, suspend, mint

Weird issue here, spent days reading old bug reports on keyboard repeats with no luck.
Tried different distros, always does the same. **Manjaro KDE**, **Kubuntu 19.10** and **Mint 19.3** all do the same.

Here's what happens:

1. Everything works fine, put laptop to sleep.
2. Wake laptop by hitting random keyboard key, login screen shows up. So far so good.
3. At this point the first key I hit gets stuck in repeat mode and indefinitely keeps repeating.
4. Unplug keyboard, plug back in -> all back to normal.
5. Reproducible 100% always.

Some other observations

- keyboard is basic HP Keyboard 100
- laptop is ThinkPad T460 (i5, 16ram, ssd...)
- built-in laptop keyboard does NOT suffer this problem, only USB keyboard
- my work laptop (Dell) with the same Mint 19.3 installation does NOT have this problem with this keyboard

I'm totally clueless as what to do and it is very annoying. Is there any log or any way to start debugging? What to look for? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try a different USB keyboard on this PC. This could be a 'corner case' where the PC is a little out of spec one way, and the USB keyboard a little out of spec in the opposite direction.